# AngularJS - Find next few elements

Tags: angularjs

Say I have:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" ng-click="findNextFew()"></div>
    <div class="child" ng-click="findNextFew()"></div>
    <div class="child" ng-click="findNextFew()"></div>
    <div class="child" ng-click="findNextFew()"></div>
    <div class="child" ng-click="findNextFew()"></div>
</div>
```

When a `.child` is clicked, I want to add a class to the `.child`, AND the next say `n` `.child`s. How can I do this in Angular? How can I find the next few items?

EDIT
What I actually want to do is something else. I used the example above to simply it:
I drag an item (of variable height) around. Say the div is 10units. I drop it on a grid with each cell being exactly 1unit in height. The binding of the drop corresponds to the top of the div being dragged. So in this example, the div would then take 10cells.

Say I drop on on cell #1 (and therefore, it will take all the cells up to #cell10). But say there is already an item on cell #8. I want to be able to check that, and prevent such a drop.